# Import XML in Google Spreadsheet - Xpath - Element contains text

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I've been fiddling for several hours to find a solution to scrapa data of about 1000 products in Google Spreadsheet.

Here's a sample of the source code:

```
<dl class="attributes">
<dt class="attr-title">Toepassing:</dt>
<dd class="attr-value">Reistas</dd>
<dt class="attr-title">Doel:</dt>
<dd class="attr-value">Reizen</dd>
<dt class="attr-title">Volume:</dt>
<dd class="attr-value">25 l</dd>
<dt class="attr-title">Materiaal:</dt>
<dd class="attr-value">Polyester</dd>
</dl>
```

I have a list of al the URL's of the products in column 1, and this in column 2:
 `=query(ImportXML(A1;"//dl//dt[contains(text'Toepassing:')]/dd");"select* limit 1")`

The result is #N/A (XML can't be parsed).

The reason I'm using the "contains text" is because the dl list is not consistent. Some do have extra, or less items. I've been using this `=query(ImportXML(A2;"//dl/dd[2]");"select* limit 1")` which did give the data, but the data and columns went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your xpath :

```
//dl//dt[contains(text(), "Toepassing:")]
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I'm afraid that didn't work. I tried these options:


`=ImportXML(A2;"//dl//dt[contains(text(); "Toepassing:")]")` and  `=query(ImportXML(A2;"//dl//dt[contains(text(), "Toepassing:")]");"select* limit 1")`


As a rookie with these kind of things, I'm on a dead end.. :-(



(PS: Google Docs requires semicolons instead of commas )